# tracing specific variable in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I want to watch specific variable in visual studio 2010.
For example,

string stringVar = "blablabla";

I want to know when this variable is created? when modified or when assigned something to it.

--

In my application, one of variable value changing abruptly and I can not figure out why and I dont want to debug whole code.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert your variable into a property and set a breakpoint in the setter?

```
string _stringVar = "blablablba";
string stringVar {
    get
    {
        return _stringVar;
    }
    set
    {
        _stringVar = value;
    }
}
```

You could always swap it back after you solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

How about a [break point with condition specified to has changed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sye83ce.aspx)

> Choose Has changed if you want to break when the value of the
>   expression has changed.

Comment: That breaks when the line is executed.  It does not break when the data actually changes.  There is a "data breakpoint" but it's not supported under .NET, only under native C++.

Comment: @MikeC it states *or choose Has changed if you want to break when the value of the expression has changed.*

Comment: it also states "The debugger does not evaluate the expression _until the first time the breakpoint is reached_." Not when the data changes; when the line is executed.